# Delete records based on another table and criteria

Tags: ms-access, inner-join

I'm using MS Access and I would like to delete some records from a **table A** based on another **Table B** and some criteria  related to dates

I worked out a query in MS Access but this one does not really work.

```
DELETE [30 - Réception].*
FROM [30 - Réception] INNER JOIN [00 - TableOfDelivery] ON [00 - TableOfDelivery].item=[30 - Réception].item
WHERE [30 - Réception].[reception date] < (select min([Delivery date]) from [00 - TableOfDelivery] where [00 - TableOfDelivery].item=[30 - Réception].item) and  [30 - Réception].[reception date] >  (select max([Delivery date]) from [00 - TableOfDelivery] where [00 - TableOfDelivery].item=[30 - Réception].item);
```

I'd like to be able to delete records based on another table and criteria related to dates

Comment: Any help? I've been google it anywhere, but no chance to find the solution

Comment: Please add a description of what you are trying to accomplish with the delete. What values do you want to delete from Table A and what are the criteria in Table B that would indicate they should be deleted?